# how to add background color for checkbox in gridview

Tags: asp.net

i have a gridview  with 5 checkbox. i need to add  for  eack checkbox  different backgound  color that is

i totally have  5 rows in gridview  with 5 checkbox  for each row  i need to add  different color

```
chececkbox1-red color
chececkbox2-green color
chececkbox3-blue color
chececkbox4-black color
chececkbox5-brown color
```

how can i get achived this  one 
any help would be great thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick solution off my mind..   this code will do the job .. if you want me to add an explination/Comments.. i'd gladly add it :)

on design side, add this property to your gridView

```
onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
```

And to your code behind add the following method:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        List<string> array = new List<string>();
        GridViewRow row = e.Row;
        switch (e.Row.RowIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                row.Cells[2].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                break;
            case 1:
                row.Cells[2].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                break;
            case 2:
                row.Cells[2].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
                break;

            case 3:
                row.Cells[2].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                break;

            case 4:
                row.Cells[2].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Brown;
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On  RowCreating event, find the cell in which the checkbox is being rendered and set the background colour of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

To me, the best way is to separate the styling into CSS wherever possible, although I don't know if your binding dynamically or not so unsure which way to designate the CSS classes required.

I did something similar using just html and css (some JS too, but that can be ignored) at: http://www.ajgraham.com/codestore/togglecheckbox/checkbox.html. From what I remember I had to colour the background of the label that wrapped the checkbox, although when you use a checkbox in a GridView it automatically creates a label with it.

I might be able to help more with more information or code samples.

Alex